# Telerik RadCombobox with multicolumn loading data very slow

Tags: radcombobox

I am working on a Telerik RadCombobox with multiple columns control to load the data around 5000 records. It is very slow while I am clicking on this control to list down the data and too slow while I am filtering the data.

Any idea, technique or algorithm to make it loading faster, please?

Answer (score 0):

use LoadOnDemand and Virtual Scrolling. For best performance load items through WebService. This should improve performance by loading data on small pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that what you are seeing it's quite normal. After all, 3000 items would have approximately  the following footprint:

25 bytes just for the items,
5 bytes for the base text
1 to 4 bytes for the counter text.

As well as some JSON data.

Multiply by 3000 and you are close more than 100 kb of postback content.

Old browsers, especially IE6, 7 and 8 are notoriously slow with that much content. Also, that content needs to be parsed to HTML elements and all JS things set.

Chrome on the other side is extremely fast and a the 100kb of content will not slow it down that much.

In order to solve this, you could use virtual scrolling and not return the entire set of data. You can read this help article on virtual scrolling to get the general idea -- http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-load-on-demand-showmoreresultsbox.html.